# How to know which implicit interface method is being use from the library

Tags: go, interface

In go language Interfaces are implemented implicitly.

```
api := http.Server{
        Addr:         cfg.Web.APIHost,
        Handler:      handlers.API(build, shutdown, log),
        ReadTimeout:  cfg.Web.ReadTimeout,
        WriteTimeout: cfg.Web.WriteTimeOut,
    }
```

As we know `Handler` requires

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

my `handlers.API` returns `*httptreemux.ContextMux` which in its library somewhere has implemented the `ServeHTTP` function.

Now my question is how do I find that particular implementation.

I am using [httptreemux](https://github.com/dimfeld/httptreemux)

Comment: All methods are explicitly declared in the package. There is also only one [`ServeHTTP` method in the entire package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dimfeld/httptreemux#TreeMux.ServeHTTP). I haven't looked to see how that router is organized, but I would start there.

Comment: On pkg.go.dev the headline for a method, functions, etc. are linked to the source code.

Comment: yes , `*httptreemux.ContextMux` has `*TreeMux` and `TreeMux` have `ServeHTTP` implementations